# Get last login details without webservicing

Tags: android

need an idea to get last  login details(DATE OF LAST LOGIN) on login  without webservicing concept

Comment: where is your code???

Comment: need an idea , unable to figure out logic , dint write any code yet

Comment: Search in _Google_ for that...we can't help you without code.

Comment: Set one flag when user login and store date and time in shared preference. After second login first get date and time from shared preference.

Answer (score 0):

Store Last login date into SQLLITE database when you need last login detail fetch this values from SQLLITE database.

Comment: tried that also, its replacing todays value , so every time i login it should show me the last login details

Comment: Store date as a  string

Comment: SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("DATE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("SUBDATE", filename);
                editor.commit();

Comment: thta where i put the string , using public static boolean to get it back but it shows current time rather than last login

Comment: i am edited my answer plz check it  instead of shared preference use sqllite database

Answer (score 0):

instead of sqlite use SharedPreferences
you will have to create an object of shared preference and an editor

it will be similiar to this:

```
     SharedPreferences sp;
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed;
    ed=sp.edit();
    ed.putBoolean("username",username);
ed.commit(); //**DONT FORGET TO COMMIT**
         sp = getSharedPreferences("MenuData", MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(!sp.contains(null))
            {
            username=sp.getBoolean("username",defaultvalue);// you need to add an default value
                if(username.equals("admin")){
                //do watever u like

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

soloved the problem,
setting the value before even putting;

```
  min=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        seconds=c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        SharedPreferences prefs1 = getSharedPreferences(
                    "DATE", MODE_PRIVATE);
           datee = prefs1.getString("SUBDATE", null);
            DATE1.setText(datee);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("DATE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("SUBDATE", min+"  "+seconds+"  ");
        editor.commit();
```